# PHP Loading data from mysql according to time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, social-networking

I am creating a social networking website using PHP and MYSQL. I am facing problem in loading posts of friends and the current user, and arranging them according to the recent. Here is my program, I know this is not a good method but this is what i could manage to code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE["uid"]))
{
    include("includes/functions.php");
    include("includes/config.php");
    $uid=$_COOKIE["uid"];
    $posts=array();
    $friends=array();
    $sql="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE uid='$uid'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $posts[]=[$row["pid"],$row["uid"],$row["post"],$row["time"]];
        }
    }
    $sql="SELECT * FROM friends WHERE uid1='$uid' OR uid2='$uid' AND status='1'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if($uid1==$uid){$friends[]=$uid2;}else{$friends[]=$uid1;}
        }
    }
    for($i=0;$i<count($friends);$i++)
    {
        $temp_uid=$friends[$i];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE uid='$temp_uid'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $posts[]=[$row["pid"],$row["uid"],$row["post"],$row["time"]];
            }
        }
    }
    $eo=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($posts);$i++)
    {
        echo "Username: ".u2u($posts[$i][1])."<br>Post Message: ".nl2br($posts[$i][2])."<br>Time: ".t2t($posts[$i][3])."<p>";
    }

}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "evenure";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
function u2u($temp_uid){
    require("../config.php");
    $sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE uid='$temp_uid'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            return $row["username"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "Invalid UID";
    }
}

function t2t($temp_time){
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $etime = time() - $temp_time;

    if ($etime < 1)
    {
        return '0 seconds';
    }

    $a = array( 365 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
                 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'month',
                      24 * 60 * 60  =>  'day',
                           60 * 60  =>  'hour',
                                60  =>  'minute',
                                 1  =>  'second'
                );
    $a_plural = array( 'year'   => 'years',
                       'month'  => 'months',
                       'day'    => 'days',
                       'hour'   => 'hours',
                       'minute' => 'minutes',
                       'second' => 'seconds'
                );

    foreach ($a as $secs => $str)
    {
        $d = $etime / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1)
        {
            $r = round($d);
            return $r . ' ' . ($r > 1 ? $a_plural[$str] : $str) . ' ago';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

My above codes work properly but the only problem is I am not able to arrange them according to the recent time, i.e., load new posts first and then old posts.

Comment: Cant you just use `ORDER BY`?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE uid='$temp_uid' ORDER BY name_of_your_date_column DESC` (ASC if you want the oldest first)

Comment: @KayNelson: You did not understand my problem yet. Say I use order by time, then i get the current users posts first, later I get the current users friends posts. But what if the friend has posted earlier than the current user? I want to arrange all the posts in the array according to the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE["uid"]))
{
    include("includes/functions.php");
    include("includes/config.php");
    $uid=$_COOKIE["uid"];
    $posts = [];
    $friends = [];
    $sql="SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friends WHERE uid1='$uid' OR uid2='$uid' AND status='1'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $friends[$uid1] = $uid1;
            $friends[$uid2] = $uid2; 
        }
    }
    $friends[$uid] = $uid;
    // $friends now contain all friends and person himself

    $friendsSql = implode(', ', $friends);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM posts WHERE uid IN ($friendsSql)' ORDER BY posts.time DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $posts[]=[$row["pid"],$row["uid"],$row["post"],$row["time"]];
        }
    }
    // $posts now contain posts of person and his friends in desc order
}
```

Comment: Thanks but instead of all those functions, you can directly add the current user to friends array like `$friends[]=$uid;`. Anyways this is working for me :)

Comment: Sorry i did not see, but you have used `$friends[]=$uid;`. Great Job

Answer (score -1):

In your sql query

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM friends WHERE uid1='$uid' OR uid2='$uid' AND status='1'";
```

you need to use `ORDER BY` clause, you did not tell the column name of the database that stores the post date and time, so let us assume the column name as `post_dt`.

From older to latest post you will write the query as:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM friends WHERE uid1='$uid' OR uid2='$uid' AND status='1' ORDER BY post_dt ASC" ;
```

For the latest to oldest post you will write it as:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM friends WHERE uid1='$uid' OR uid2='$uid' AND status='1' ORDER BY post_dt DESC ";
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Nope, you are not getting my point. Its not just the posts of the current user, but also his friends. So first I get all the posts of the user and then his friends, but what if his friend has posted earlier to the current user? This will not help in my situation :(

Comment: @Manikiran,for that you need to use an interval type of function in jquery that will be executing for the time limit that you provide in the function and will be updating the user page in that interval. Any how you will need to ORDER BY operator to perform arranging to result.